# Прибавление +1 каждые новые сутки к числу на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет! С jquery знаком не очень близко, в основном использую для анимаций, всяких аккордионов и пр. В общем, есть такая задача:
Имеем число, к примеру 200. Нужно сделать так, чтобы каждые новые сутки начальное число увеличивалось на +1. Т.е. так, чтобы через 30 дней было не 200, а 230.
Я прекрасно понимаю, что это практически не сложно, но к сожалению, не имел пока такой практики. Заранее благодарю вас.

Comment: Храните число в базе (текстовом файле), раз в сутки инкрементируйте кроном. Делать такие вещи на клиенте -> Bad practice ;(

Comment: Поковырялся с кодом, который предоставил DreamChild, в общем проблема в том, что если поставить, к примеру, дату 12/12/2013, то на выходе ничего не происходит, просто NaN. Я так понял, что сравнение идет только с числом, но ни как не связанно с месяцем и годом. А мне нужно поставить дату с 13 апреля 2013 года. Я так понял, что на jquery это не реально сделать.

Comment: @vovanzo, ничего ты не понял.  

   var startDate = new Date('12/12/2013').getTime() / 86400;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C2ybQ/1/

Comment: @Олег Б Хороший пример, спасибо. Но мои знания не совсем позволяют разобраться с этим кодом(( Я не понимаю относительно какой даты идет отсчет? Как сделать от конкретной даты, интересно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если хотите все делать на клиенте, то сделайте что-нибудь такое:

```
<input type='hidden' value = '02/01/2014' id='startDate' />
<input type='hidden' value = '100' id='startCounter' />

$().ready(    
function() {               
    var day = 24*60*60*1000
    var firstDate = new Date($('#startDate').val());  
    var secondDate = new Date();
    var startCounter = $('#startCounter').val();
    var daysPassed = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(day))  - 1);

    alert(daysPassed + parseInt(startCounter));
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вот только вопрос, как мне результат daysPassed + parseInt(startCounter)впихнуть в блок div в параграф p?

Comment: Так надо?  

    $('div p').text(daysPassed + parseInt(startCounter));

Comment: Если вам подошло, то создайте на странице любой элемент скажем:

    <div class="counter__result"></div>

и на результат ему таким образом:

    $('.counter__result').text(daysPassed + parseInt(startCounter));

Comment: >Вот только вопрос, как мне результат daysPassed + parseInt(startCounter) впихнуть в блок div в параграф p?

ну уж хоть с этим-то сами разберитесь, элементарно ведь

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Все получилось! Такой вопрос, чисто для практики: можно ли сделать, что бы прибавлялось не по 1, по рандомному числу из какого-либо диапазона, скажем от 3 до 7?

Comment: >что бы прибавлялось не по 1, по рандомному числу из какого-либо диапазона

на клиенте вы это не сделаете - эти данные нужно где-то хранить. Поэтому для прибавления случайной величины вам нужно переносить эту логику на сервер

Comment: Поковырялся с кодом, который предоставил DreamChild, в общем проблема в том, что если поставить, к примеру, дату 12/12/2013, то на выходе ничего не происходит, просто NaN. Я так понял, что сравнение идет только с числом, но ни как не связанно с месяцем и годом. А мне нужно поставить дату с 13 апреля 2013 года. Я так понял, что на jquery это не реально сделать.

Comment: >Я так понял, что сравнение идет только с числом, но ни как не связанно с месяцем и годом. А мне нужно поставить дату с 13 апреля 2013 года. Я так понял, что на jquery это не реально сделать

Не говорите ерунды, все нормально работает: [пример][1]. Вы скорее всего неправильно пишете дату

[1]:http://jsfiddle.net/LS3jK/2/

Comment: @DreamChild, скорее, он не знает, что с ней делать...

Comment: @DreamChild не ругайся) Спасибо большое, все работает как нужно! Посоветуй, пожалуйста, литературу по jquery.

Comment: @vovanzo начните даже не с JQuery, а с JavaScript (JQuery - это всего лишь библиотека для этого языка). Сам по себе JS не сложен (во всяком случае в своих основах). Для этого есть большая и замечательная книга Дэвида Флэнагана, а также вполне неплохой отечественный сайт javascript.ru. Если необходим именно JQuery, то можете почитать книгу "jQuery. Подробное руководство по продвинутому JavaScript", а также ознакомиться с сайтом jquery.docs.ru, думаю, этого более чем достаточно

Answer (score 4):

С использованием плагина [**jquery-cookie**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):

```
function daysPassed(startTime) {
    return Math.floor(((new Date().getTime() / 86400) - startTime));
}
var startValue = 200;
var startTime = new Date().getTime() / 86400;
if (typeof $.cookie('startTime') === 'undefined') {
    $.cookie('startTime', startTime);
} else {
    startTime = $.cookie('startTime');
}
setInterval(function() {
    console.log(startValue + daysPassed(startTime));
}, 86400);
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/G6NTL/3/)** (значение меняется каждые 5 сек)

Answer (score -3):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var num = 1;
setInterval(function () {
    num++;
    $(".number").html(num);
}, 24*60*60*1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UY6Q7/13/

Comment: 24 часа * 60 мин * 60 секунд, где 1000 - это одна секунда?

Comment: хорошо хоть не sleep(24*60*60*1000) (да, я в курсе, что в JS нет sleep)

Comment: setInterval устанавливается в миллисекундах, поэтому 24 часа * 60 минут * 60 секунд * 1000 миллисекунд

Comment: @DreamChild а как надо? )

Comment: Так, я понял, что это мне не совсем подходит, т.к. нужно чтобы именно каждый новый календарный день добавлялось +1. Как это реализовать?