# Как с помощью скрипта изменить значение переменной предварительно вычислив его отталкиваясь от даты?

Tags: jquery

Есть данная конструкция, она позволяет анимировать счетчик от нуля до указанного в настройках скрипта значения.

Как правильно добавить дополнительную функцию чтобы, к значению прибавлялся результат двух множителей

1-й множитель: шаг(установленное значение)

2-й множитель: число (дней, часов, лет) прошедших от указанной в скрипте даты (например 01 мая 2018)

Полученную сумму нужно прибавить к имеющимся в скрипте значениям:

у блока с классом `nyear` значение `number` изменялось каждый календарный год на +1

у блока с классом `nclient` значение `number` изменялось каждые календарные сутки на +10

у блока классом `nproduct` значение `number` изменялось каждые час на +5

пример: сейчас для числа с классом `nyear` установлено значение `number` 20 необходимо чтобы в 1 января 2019 года к данному числу был прибавлен +1 и в итоге анимированный счетчик покажет значение 21

или

пример: сейчас для числа с классом `nclient` установлено значение `number` 7100 сегодня 19 мая 2018 с момента начала отсчета (1 мая 2018) прошло 19 дней (раз значение меняется каждые сутки на +10 19х10=190) анимированный счетчик должен показывать 7290

Буду очень признателен за решение в виде скрипта!

```js
$('.nyear')
  .prop('number', 0)
  .animateNumber({
      number: 20
    },
    2000
  );

$('.nclient')
  .prop('number', 0)
  .animateNumber({
      number: 7100
    },
    2000
  );

$('.nproduct')
  .prop('number', 0)
  .animateNumber({
      number: 22130
    },
    2000
  );
```

```css
.nb {
  background: #0e581b;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.nb div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.nyear,
.nclient,
.nproduct {
  font-size: 22px;
  display: block;
}

.nb .td {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-animateNumber/0.0.14/jquery.animateNumber.min.js"></script>

<div class="nb">
  <div>
    <span class="nyear"> </span> <span class="td">лет на рынке</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="nclient"> </span> <span class="td">счастливых клиентов</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="nproduct"> </span> <span class="td">проданных товаров</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилась немного громоздкая конструкция, но так как работает за неимением другого варианта пока остановился на этом. Может быть кому-то пригодится.

Удалось реализовать задуманное (см. вопрос) с помощью немного другого скрипта анимации чисел:
https://github.com/johnjcamilleri/jquery-spincrement и решения предложенного на страницах stackoverflow в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/302113/232533

Отсчет ведется от 01 января 2018 года. (дата указана в скрытом поле)
Значения для множителей (с какого числа начинать отсчет и какой шаг использовать) берутся из настроек скрипта.

В итоге значения меняются с учетом хода времени (каждый час/день/год) для разных показателей задан свой шаг изменений.

Меняя время / начальную дату отсчета или значения множителей (начальное значение+шаг) можно проверить что считается все корректно (надеюсь).

Если будет предложен более компактный вариант, буду признателен т.к. с jQuery знаком очень поверхностно.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var firstDate = new Date($('#startDate').val());
  var secondDate = new Date();
  var startCounter = $('#startCounter').val();
  var ystep = 1; // шаг для значения год - будет увеличиватся на одну еденицу каждый календарный год 
  var ynumstart = 19; //стартовое значение года
  var clstep = 10; // шаг для значения клиенты - будет увеличиватся на 10 едениц каждые сутки
  var clnumstart = 7100; //стартовое значение клиентов
  var prodstep = 5; // шаг для значения товары - будет увеличиватся на 5 едениц каждый час
  var prodnumstart = 22130; //стартовое значение товаров
  var ynumvalue = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / (day) / 365) + ystep + ynumstart);
  var clnumvalue = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / (day)) * clstep + clnumstart);
  var prodnumvalue = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / (day) * 24 * 5) + prodstep + prodnumstart);

  $('.nyear').text(ynumvalue).spincrement({
    thousandSeparator: "",
    duration: 5000
  });


  $('.nclient').text(clnumvalue).spincrement({
    thousandSeparator: "",
    duration: 5000
  });



  $('.nproduct').text(prodnumvalue).spincrement({
    thousandSeparator: "",
    duration: 5000
  });

});
```

```css
.nb {
  background: #0e581b;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.nb div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.nyear,
.nclient,
.nproduct {
  font-size: 22px;
  display: block;
}

.nb .td {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/johnjcamilleri/jquery-spincrement/master/jquery.spincrement.min.js"></script>



<div class="nb">
  <input type="hidden" value="01/01/2018" id="startDate" />
  <div>
    <span class="nyear"> </span> <span class="td">лет на рынке</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="nclient"> </span> <span class="td">счастливых клиентов</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="nproduct"> </span> <span class="td">проданных товаров</span>
  </div>
</div>
```